# Using Chained Promise.allSettled

Tags: javascript, promise, fetch

For a quick rundown of what I'm trying to do. I've got a basic `for` loop that generates an array of IPs that I want to fetch. I want to check that the `response.status` is 200 (Which I haven't implemented yet) and then take the IPs that returned a status of 200 and only keep those IPs.

I’ve tried doing this with `Promise.all` but was left with the problem of it rejecting one, thus rejecting all of them. So now I'm at this code.

```
async function example() {
    var arr = [];
    for (let i = 4; i <= 255; i++) {
        var ip = 'http://172.16.238.' + i.toString() + ':443';
        arr.push(ip);
    }
    Promise.allSettled(arr.map(u=>fetch(u))).then(responses => Promise.allSettled(responses.map(res => res.text()))).then(texts => {fetch('https://testing.com', {method: 'POST', body: texts})})
}
example()
```

I'm getting `res.text()` isn't a function when used with `allSettled`. But I'm also confused as to how I would approach checking the status of each response. I'm mapping the url to each fetch and then mapping a response to it's text, so would I do the status check in the second mapping? The mapping is a bit confusing to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`allSettled` does not return an array with the resolved values - rather, it returns an array of *objects*, where the objects contain `status` / `value` / `reason` properties. To get to the resolve value, if there is one, access the `.value` property.

But a single `allSettled` will do - call `.text` inside the first callback if it hasn't errored.

```
function example() {
    var arr = [];
    for (let i = 4; i <= 255; i++) {
        var ip = 'http://172.16.238.' + i.toString() + ':443';
        arr.push(ip);
    }
    Promise.allSettled(arr.map(
        u => fetch(u)
            .then(res => { if (res.ok) return res.text(); })
    ))
        .then(results => {
            const texts = results
                .filter(result => result.status === 'fulfilled' && result.value)
                .map(result => result.value);
            fetch('https://testing.com', { method: 'POST', body: texts })
                // ...
        })
}
```